# Vector distances with extra factors

Tags: algorithm, math, vector, distance

I'm working on a k-means algorythm, which is currently functional but I'm looking for an alternate formula to use an extra factor, namely the relevance of the points of 1 of the 2 vectors I calculate the distance between.

**Summary of what I'm doing so far:**

I assign a vector to entries in the database and use k-means to assign all entries to a cluster. I then check a random point for nearby clusters and gather the entries that are closer than a certain factor.

This all works and after the clustering is complete I can pick a random new point and gather the closest clusters and database entries within that. I than however still have to determine relevance of those entries and I want to do that by using a factor withing the distance calculation after that.

Basically I have to calculate distance between point X and multiple points C(n)
all points are 3D vectors

D(n) = SQRT( (X1-C1)² + (X2-C2)² + (X3-C3)² )

What I want is an extra factor within every point in C that makes the distance shorter if it matches and makes it bigger if it doesnt match at all. The relevance is 0 for not relevant at all, and then 1 2 or 3 for very relevant. Basically if C1 is relevance 3 and X1 is NOT the same the distance should be WAY bigger but if X1 == C1 the distance should be minimal because C1 with relevance 3 counts way stronger than C2 and C3 with relevances 1 for example.

I hope I made myself clear and someone can help me out :)

Comment: I've tried multiple things basically playing with the numbers 0,1,2,3 on different locations within the formula. Replace the ^2 with the relevance. Dividing the (X1-C1)² by the relevance. Multiplying C1 with the relevance etc. The distances change obviously but I;'m looking for a function that makes it smaller when the same and bigger when not which is above my capabilities :)

Comment: There seems to be a confusion : is C1 the first point or a coordinate ? Should it read C1(n) ? Then should we reweight (X1-C1(n))^2 or D(n) ?

Comment: I mean C(n)1 C(n)2 etc. so the different coordinates in the vector. In this case only 3 but will be an 8 dimensional vector later on.

I want to reweigh every coordinate in a vector based on a relevance factor which makes the final distance D smaller if the coordinates match and bigger if they don't .

Comment: Have you tried a weighted sum ?
D(n)  = sqrt( a1^2 (x1-c(n)1)^2 + a2^2 (x2-c(n)2)^2 + ..) / sqrt(a1^2 + a2^2 + ..)

Comment: I tried it out on wolframalpha.com and this looks like exactly what i need. Basically 2 vectors that had the same distance to a point have a different distance because of the relevance factor now. It's too muchformula's in wolfram to show you the results but thank you so much!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a weighted sum ? D(n) = sqrt( a1^2 (x1-c(n)1)^2 + a2^2 (x2-c(n)2)^2 + ..) / sqrt(a1^2 + a2^2 + ..)

where the a1, a2, .. are some factors that take into account the relevance of each coordinate